# What best explains the 'perspective' effect in this image?

Tags: geometry, soft-question

I found this image and I would like to replicate the effect algorithmically. How would one describe this distortion effect mathematically? The rate of change of scale seems very familiar, and the non-straight edges implies more than just a scaling effect. Sorry for the rather naive question...

[image: Image taken from TED with an interesting perspective]

Comment: Looks like Moebius transformation.

Comment: The image seems to be from [TED : Math talks to blow your mind](http://www.ted.com/playlists/189/math_talks_to_blow_your_mind).

Comment: Google reverse image search? Or did you happen to recognize the picture?

Comment: The image seems to have been especially made as a cover for the video series, and reverse image search doesn't yield any other examples. What interests me is that it seems to be plotted in mathematica, using a mathematical property that "seems familiar". Its almost annoying as trying to find out what a [Fibonacci spiral like this](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/seeds5000.gif) is without knowing the name :)

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee, Google reverse image search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of view is at the origin.  The nodes seen are at 3-D points with integer coordinates, and say, with $x > 1$ so that you are not worrying about the point you are sitting on.  And you are looking at a projection, say onto the plane $x=\rho$; for example, $\rho = 1/2$ places the plane right in front of your eyes.

For each point, you transform that point into spherical coordinates via
$$ \begin{array}{c}
r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} \\
\phi = \tan^{-1} \frac{y}{x} \\
\theta = \sin^{-1} \frac{z}{r}
\end{array}
$$

Now you project the line of that $(\phi, \theta)$ and parameterized by $r$ varying, onto the plane at $x=1/2$.  That is, you solve
$$ r \cos \theta \cos \phi = \rho$$
and you plug in that $r$ to find the $(y,z)$ of where to draw the point; $x$ is ignored.

For example, if $\rho = 1/2$ the grid point $(12,3,4)$ whould have
$$ \begin{array}{c}
r = 13 \\
\phi = \tan^{-1} \frac{3}{13} \\
\theta = \sin^{-1} \frac{4}{13}
\end{array}
$$
$$
\cos \theta \cos \phi \approx 0.923
$$
$$ 
r_{x=1/2} = \frac{1/2}{\cos \theta \cos \phi } \approx 0.542\\
$$
So at that projection plane,
$$ \begin{array}{c}
y_{x=1/2} = r_{x=1/2} \cos \theta \sin \phi = 0.125\\
y_{x=1/2} = r_{x=1/2} \cos \theta \sin \phi = 0.125\\
r_{x=1/2} \sin \theta = 0.167
\end{array}
$$
so you would draw that point at $(\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{6})$ in your picture (the example was chosen such that the numbers worked out nicely).
$$

It's a lot easier to code this up than to do it by hand, and modern GPU's are good at doing it for many millions of  points every second to render drawings such as this one.

Comment: Thankyou, I'll take your word for it and start coding something up! - is there a name for the projection you are describing?

Comment: There is, but I can't remember it just now.